# Working with AVI files in C#

Tags: c#

I need to create an application in C# capable of playing AVI files and cutting certain portions of it write subtiles for marked portions etc. Which library should I use for basic play/forward/stop operations?

Answer (score 2):

I've not used it but a quick google turned up [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/avi_files.html)

Comment: I love the AForge.NET framework. The only downside with it, is that it is using DirectShow that has been deprecated by Microsoft (without giving us a good replacement).

Comment: @PatrikSvensson What is replacement if directshow is obsolete from Microsoft?

Comment: @qtg No idea. It was 11 years ago I wrote that answer.